# How to grep a string in a file and output the digits next to the string

Tags: grep

I am trying to print out a number next to a string that I search (using shell script).

For ex., my file contains a line

```
arg[30] = -Xmx4096m
```

I search the file with string `Xmx` and I need the output of next digits attached to the string and nothing else is needed in the output. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your version of `grep` supports PCRE mode, you can use `grep -Po 'Xmx\K\d+'`

Ex.

```
echo 'F arg[30] = -Xmx4096m' | grep -Po 'Xmx\K\d+'
4096
```

Comment: unfortunately not, but thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -n 's/.*Xmx\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/p' filename
```

Explanation:

- `sed -n` makes sed only print output when told (by `p`)
- `s/<p1>/<p2>/p` search for `<p1>` and replace with `<p2>`. then print line
- `.*Xmx\([0-9]\+\).*` any string with `Xmx` followed by digits. the digits are "captured".
- `\1` the first captured group.

In human words: search for lines containing `Xmx` followed by digits. Take note of the digits. Discard everything but keep the digits. Print the digits.